# "PKIX path building failed:" "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" for remote server

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I am getting this error in my tomcat catalina.out log:

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

when trying to access this remote URL: https://remote-hostname-fqdn-here:8443.  This works fine when the same call is made locally.

I have the certificate imported into the keystore, i.e.  I see the following when I list the certs content with keytool:

```
$ /opt/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore /opt/apache-tomcat/conf/ssl/cacerts | grep icr

Alias name: remote-hostname-fqdn-here
Creation date: Jan 4, 2018
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=remote-hostname-fqdn-here, O="Org-name-removed", L=Place-removed, ST=State-removed, C=US
Issuer: CN=remote-hostname-fqdn-here, O="Org-name-removed", L=Place-removed, ST=State-removed, C=US
Serial number: serial-number-removed 
Valid from: Thu Jan 04 13:22:32 CST 2018 until: Sun Jan 02 13:22:32 CST 2028
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  md5sum-value-removed 
         SHA1: sha1-value-removed 
         SHA256: sha256-value-removed 
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 1
```

Note that I have tomcat instances in two environments, both running Java jdk1.7.0_75 and Tomcat 7.0.90, and the same SSL connector configuration.  Strangely enough, this error only happens on one of them, even though we've tried the same action to clear the application cache to trigger the error on both.

While I do have a wildcard cert (different from the cert mentioned here) configured in server.xml on all the servers, I can see it logical that I'd have to import that cert into the keystore.  However, I haven't imported it on either environment, so I'm at a loss as to why I'm only getting this error in one environment.  Note that other than this functionality of clearing a remote server's application cache, all other aspects of SSL seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Importing the wildcard cert that covered the same domain as the current ones for each server solved the problem.  Still don’t know why I wasn’t able to recreate the problem in the other environment.  While the .war and .jar files were different, I was told the portion of the code for the problem here is the same.